# Double typed literal in Apache Jena

Tags: jena, literals

I want to create an object in a triple with a datatype Double. I have the following code:

```
 if(!spine.equals(null)){
      register_res.addProperty(spineWidth, model.createTypedLiteral(new XSDDouble(spine)));
 }
```

I am reading spine from a csv file and saving it in a String.

I am getting the following error:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDatatype.<init>(XSDDatatype.java:231)
at org.apache.jena.datatypes.xsd.impl.XSDDouble.<init>(XSDDouble.java:38)
at VolumesUpload.main(VolumesUpload.java:140)
```

Any idea what is wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

`XSDDouble` is the class of the datatype, not the value.

You want:

```
model.createTypedLiteral("4.5", XSDDatatype.XSDdouble);
```

if spine is the lexical form of the value or

```
model.createTypedLiteral(Double.valueOf("4.5"));
```

to create from a value.